# How to ensure that linked projects get added to source control

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015

I have a solution directory as shown below:

[image]

The first four projects are located in one directory, the latter two are utility projects that get linked to more that one solution.

I am using Git as source control and Team foundation services as the remote repository.

Simple question: when I first published the solution to the remote branch it copied the first four projects but not the last two, why did it do that and how do I ensure that the latter two also get committed?

Does it mean in reality that all projects must be in the same local repository (and if that is the case then how do you allow for assemblies that one uses across solutions?).

Answer (score 1):

> Does it mean in reality that all projects must be in the same local repository (and if that is the case then how do you allow for assemblies that one uses across solutions?).

You should use git submodules for this task.

***`Submodule`*** is a **standalone** git project so the code will be checked out to a **new folder** under the root folder and it's not part of your master branch.

Your root folder will contain a submodule file and you will have to "int && update" it on every clone you make.

```
# Add the desired submodule ot your code base
git submodule add <url>
```

Now you must run two commands:

```
# init the submodule
git submodule init
```

to initialize your local configuration file, and

```
git submodule update
```

to fetch all the data from that project and check out the appropriate commit listed in your superproject:

So the full script is this:

```
git submodule add <url>
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

---

As you can see in the image submodule is simply a sub-project inside your project.

Its exactly what you described. 3rd party code for the "main" project.

[image]

Comment: Aha.  Can't say that I've come across those before, is that something that's relatively easy to do from within the solution explorer in visual studio?  I'm still trying to master git and I'd rather not mess up this solution.

Comment: Im a UNIX guy so im working form the command line (git bash in your case). Do it from git bash as described above.

Comment: @DomSinclair you can also do this with tortoisegit as a gui opposite to the cli version.

Comment: Thank you for the additional explanation, I shall look into how I can do this from within visual studio, or use the command line approach from within visual studio.  MS seem to be heavily committed to Git now so logically it should be doable.